# Dates are replaced by 1970-01-01 when inserting into clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I'm trying to insert data into a clickhouse table. Data is inserted but I got dates from 1970 (it may be 1970-01-01 or 1970-02-02 etc.)
Why can this be happening?
I have several fields with dates, but the problem only relates to one of them. I woupld expect to have 1970 if there was null in the inserting select, but it is not the case. So I got 1970 instead of a noraml value.

Comment: We don't have crystal balls, so you'll need to create a [mre] and add it to the post.

Answer (score 0):

A date. Stored in two bytes as the number of days since 1970-01-01 (unsigned). Allows storing values from just after the beginning of the Unix Epoch to the upper threshold defined by a constant at the compilation stage (currently, this is until the year 2149, but the final fully-supported year is 2148).

Supported range of values: [1970-01-01, 2149-06-06].
from  [enter link description here](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/date)

If the inserted date is not within this range, it will be converted to 1970-01-01